# Why this function returns a different value?

Tags: pointers

I've got a function which takes uint16_t variable

```
uint8_t myFunction(uint16_t myVar);
```

This case it functions properly

```
myFunction(0x04);
```

In this case it gives me a different and wrong result:

```
uint16_t* myPointer;
*myPointer = 0x04;
myFunction(*myPointer);
```

Whats the difference between the two addressing?

Comment: It sounds like you may have some misconceptions about how pointers work - you aren't allocating any memory.

Comment: I didn't study programming and I thought this should work, but it seems I should read about pointers again.

Comment: Harcoding a pointer to point at some specific bit of memory is a shockingly terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oliver commented, that's not how pointers work.

When you wrote:

```
*myPointer = 0x04;
```

You are dereferncing an uninitialized pointer here.

Either -

```
uint16_t myVal;
myVal = 0x04;
myFunction(myVal);
```

Don't use a pointer, or -

```
uint16_t* myPointer = (uint16_t*) malloc(sizeof(uint16_t));
*myPointer = 0x04;
myFunction(*myPointer);
```

Allocate memory for your pointer on the heap. Note that for using malloc() in the second method, you will have to include stdlib.h

Comment: Thank you! Clear enough.  Actually  I used in this way, because I read that arrays and pointers actually the same, and when you define an array you don't have to allocate memory. Then in case of arrays, it's done automatically if I understand well.

Comment: When you create arrays without pointers, the identifier acts as a pointer, but the actual array has not been dynamically allocated as you would using malloc(). You could also create an array on the heap using malloc(). Let me know if you need more clarification.